# Access IIS Server Variables In Nancy Module

Tags: asp.net, nancy

The Nancy.Request object replaces the System.Web.HttpRequest object, which is where you would normally find the ServerVariables collection. Is there other way to get at that information? Specifically, I need the LOGON_USER object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From inside the module, you can call

```
Context.CurrentUser.UserName
```

This is Nancy specific call and [assumes certain containers populating it](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nancy-web-framework/n9X6yg5pI0w). Otherwise, Context will be null.

If you are hosting Nancy in regular ASP.NET environment, you can still try

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]
```

Comment: Context.CurrentUser was null, but System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request was valid! Thanks so much.